# Flexible search option with execute array parameters

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying make a flexible search option but params didn't work in execute array. Can I get help about this?

```
$extra = '';
$params = array();

$sql = "SELECT brand_id,brand_status,brand_name FROM brands ORDER BY brand_name";

$brand_status = "";
$brand_name = "su";

if($brand_status) {
    $extra .= "brand_status=:brand_status and ";
    $params[] = array(
        "brand_status" => $brand_status
    );
}
if($brand_name) {
    $extra .= "brand_name LIKE :brand_name and ";
    $params[] = array(
        "brand_name" => "%" . $brand_name . "%"
    );
}

if(count($params) > 0) {
    if(strlen($extra) > 0) {
        $extra = substr($extra, 0, -5);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT brand_id,brand_status,brand_name FROM brands WHERE $extra ORDER BY brand_name";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute(array(
        $params
    ));
} else {
    $result = $query = $db->query($sql);
}

if($result)
    $num = $query->rowCount();
if($num > 0) {
    while($row = $query->fetch()) {
        echo $row['brand_name'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

If brand_name value is empty code working good. Can I do flexible search option with execute array parameters without use bindParam or bindValue?

Comment: As $params is  already an array, I think you should be using `$query->execute($params);` otherwise your wrapping the array in another array.

Comment: And replace these `$params[] = array("brand_status" => $brand_status);` with `$params['brand_status'] = $brand_status`. The parameters array must be a single dimension associative array.

Comment: Instead of `substr($extra, 0, -5)` I'd use `rtrim($extra, ' and ')`.

Answer (score 0):

Nigel Ren, marekful and user3783243 a lot of thanks for answers and ideas.

Didn't work with : `execute($params)`

Did work with : `params['brand_status'] = $brand_status`

and good idea for : `rtrim($extra, ' and ')`

NOTE: I should answer my question like this or I should edit my questions with answers? If I did wrong sorry for this.